# i have issus with likes button with ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

i was make an like button after click button the div will reload in first click it's worked fine and must be able to click #unlike but it's wont work right whene div refreshd the #unlike dose not work need to refreash whole page
this is my logic of button

```
<div class="" id="likebutton{{ $article->id }}">
                                   <div class="" id="content{{ $article->id }}">

                                <span>
                                <i type="button"
                   @if (in_array($article->id , App\User::find(Auth::user()->id)->like()->pluck('article_id')->toArray()))
                                    id="unlike"
                                    class="unlike fas fa-heart ms-2 float-end"
                                    style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: rgb(255, 34, 82);"
                                    @else
                                    class="like far fa-heart ms-2 float-end"
                                     style="font-size: 1.5rem; color: aliceblue;"
                                     @endif
                                    data-id="{{ $article->id }}"
                                     >
                                </i>

                          <a href="{{ route('articles.show', $article->slug)}}" role="button">
                                <i type="button"
                                class="far fa-eye"
                                style="font-size: 1.5rem;color: aliceblue;">
                                </i>
                           </a>
                        </span>

                             </div>
                         </div>
```

and this ajax

```
function like(id = null) {
    return $.ajax("{{ route('likes') }}", {
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
           "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
           " id" : id
        }
    });
}
 $('#unlike').click(function() {
        var id = ($(this).data("id"));
        let request = like($(this).data('id'));
        request.done(() => {
          // $('#like-'+id+'').removeClass("unlike fas fa-heart").addClass("like far fa-heart");
           $('#likebutton'+id+'').load(window.location.href + ' #content'+id+' > *');
        });
    });
$(function() {
    $('.like').click(function() {
        var id = ($(this).data("id"));
        let request = like($(this).data('id'));
        request.done(() => {
            //$('#like-'+id+'').removeClass("like far fa-heart").addClass("unlike fas fa-heart");
            $('#likebutton'+id+'').load(window.location.href + ' #content'+id+' > *');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: change $('#unlike') to $('.unlike')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for unlike
$(document).on('click', '#unlike', function() {

for like
$(document).on('click', '.like', function() {

change these two lines

Comment: thank you so much it's work now perfectly <3